# How to grab text from a ul li Item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I have a ul list and would like to run a search on them, This list poplates a ddSlick drop down box. ddSlick is a nice way to add pictures to list Items. http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick

The code i use to loop though the items are as follows:

```
$("#txtSearch").blur(function () {
  $('#MarkieItems').each(function(i, items_list){
  $(items_list).find('li').each(function(j, li){
    //alert(li.TextContent);
    var text = li.TextContent;
  })
});
```

When i inspect element and look at the text = li.TextContent it says undifined, but if i inspect the li it shows that textContent is there.

[image]

[image]

Could someone tell me how to grab this text?

Comment: is it because it should be textContent(); ?

Comment: I think, it should be li.textContent (small 't')

Comment: Omw i can't believe i missed that. Thanks Vinoth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)(small `t`)

```
var text = li.textContent;
```

but for [cross browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent#Browser_compatibility) use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) from jQuery

```
var text = $(li).text();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#MarkieItems li').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to access `li.TextContent` however the attribute is according to your screen dump called `textContent`Ie with a lower case `t`

Since you are already using jQuery you could utilize the text method

```
var text = $(this).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have jQuery you could use [text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/) to grab only text from li.

Answer (score 1):

Use `textContent` instead of `TextContent` bcoz it's case sensitive

Answer (score 1):

You've written TextContent in your javascript in **PascalCase**, whereas you should write it in **camelCase**.

Try

```
var text = li.textContent;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#txtSearch").blur(function () {
  $('#MarkieItems').each(function(i, items_list){
  $(items_list).find('li').each(function(j, li){
    //alert(li.TextContent);
    var text = li.text(); //<-----here ".text()"
  })
});
```

`.text()` method of jQuery will get you the textContent of the target dom node.